# Filter Column in GridView won't works correctly WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, collections, view

I have a gridView and I would like to filter column using `Equals` instead of `Contains` or `StartWith` . My object is to get only rows that have the exact Id in input TextBox.

As example :

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | Alice |
| 150 | John |
| 1505 | Philips |
| 1509 | Karl |
| 95150 | Eric |
| 12 | Mark |
| 16 | Susan |

- In the Textbox:

**Id = 150**

- With Contains : it will show the rows that contains ID

  => 150, 1505 , 1509 , 95150
- With Equals :

  => 150 ( but when I clear the result , it will show nothing !! )
- With StartWith : it will show the rows with ID

  => 150, 1505 , 1509

Expected result :

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 150 | John |

When I clear the Textbox

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | Alice |
| 150 | John |
| 1505 | Philips |
| 1509 | Karl |
| 95150 | Eric |
| 12 | Mark |
| 16 | Susan |

This is my code:

```
 private void ID_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
                GridView.ItemsSource = users.ToList();
                ListCollectionView view = (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(users);
                view.Filter = delegate (object item) { return (item as User).ID.Equals(IDtxt.Text.ToString()); };
                GridView.ItemsSource = view;
            

        }
        catch (Exception es)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error!" + es);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, your equals approach works, except when IDtxt.Text is empty.

When IDtxt.Text is empty, it contains an empty string, "", while the id the filter checks against is anything but an empty string -> your filter will filter out any id it comes across because IDtxt.Text never equals your id. To fix it, just check if your IDtxt is empty first:

instead of

```
view.Filter = delegate (object item) { return (item as User).ID.Equals(IDtxt.Text.ToString()); };
```

->

```
view.Filter = delegate (object item)
{
    string strFilter = IDtxt.Text.ToString();
    return strFilter.Length == 0 || (item as User).ID.Equals(strFilter);
};
```

If your filter string is empty, don't filter anything.